# My App in release mode fails the WACK (windows app cert kit) test due to ML.timeseries useage

Tags: c#, .net, time-series, ml.net, wack

> Supported APIs
> Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
> API K32EnumProcessModules in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. libiomp5md.dll calls this API.
> API GetDllDirectoryA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MklImports.dll calls this API.
> Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
> How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. If the DLL listed is an allowable redistributable from a NuGET package, SDK or other toolkit, did you forget to add the DLL to your app? Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information:
> Alternatives to Windows APIs in Microsoft Store apps.

Are there any workarounds for this?

My App in release mode using .NET native compiler fails the WACK test on this single issue directly related to the ML.TimeSeries usage (NUGET package).On removing the usage the WACK test succeeds.

Are there any know workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Beyond not using ML.TimeSeries what workaround are you hoping for?

Comment: I am only looking for a workaround to allow me to use ML.TimeSeries which seems to use intelMKL? Maybe there is a compatible version of this or similar?

Comment: The WACK test tells you that you can't use that library if you want to get certified.  But what is the point?  UWP is dead, Windows App SDK is the new approach.  Migration help [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk-ovw).

Comment: Thank you,yes I know what the WACK test is telling me and I appreciate your advice but your solution isn't a workaround more of a rebuild.